# How to get a specific column value from binding source?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, get, field, bindingsource

I have a `BindingSource` that is bound to a `DataTable` in a `DataSet`.

How can I get a specific column value from the `BindingSource` and not from the controls?

For example, something like: `Msgbox(bindingsource.item(0).value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the `BindigSource` into a `DataRowView` then get the data column, like:

```
MsgBox(CType(bindingsource.Current, DataRowView).Item(1))
```

Get value from current row on `BindigSource` and `column(1)`.

Or try this:

```
MsgBox(CType(bindingsource.List(0), DataRowView).Item(1))
```

Get value from row 0, column 1 from `BindigSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
MsgBox(bindingsource.Rows(0).Item(1))
```

This gets the value from row 0 and column 1.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for your question:

```
Dim myItme As String = dataTableName.Rows.Item(0).Item("ColumnNameOrIndex")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

MsgBox(bindingsource.Current!MyField)